# Creating a read more button with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using html, css and javascript to create a read more button. I have a paragraph and if this button is pressed, more text will de displayed.

This is my html code

```
<p class="details">Text that is displayed><span class="read-more">More text</span></p>
<button class="read-more-button">Read more</button>

//on the bottom of the page I also added the scripts
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

In my css file I make the paragraph between the span tag not visible

```
.details .read-more{
    display:none;
}
```

In my javascript

```
const readMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.read-more-button');
const text = document.querySelector('.details');


readMoreBtn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    details.classList.toggle('read-more');
})
```

The problem is that when I press the Read more button nothing happens, the paragraph between the span tag is not displayed. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target `.read-more` class, not `.details`.
Also, there is a undefined variable in event listener.
The correct JS code should be:

```
const readMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.read-more-button');
const text = document.querySelector('.read-more');


readMoreBtn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    text.classList.toggle('read-more');
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You're toggling the class of `p.details`. You should toggle the class of `.read-more'.

```js
const readMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.read-more-button');
const moreText = document.querySelector('.read-more');

readMoreBtn.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
  moreText.classList.toggle('read-more');
  
  // Consider changing the button text to collapse or removing it altogether perhaps?
})
```

```css
.details .read-more{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<p class="details">Text that is displayed<span class="read-more">More text</span></p>
<button class="read-more-button">Read more</button>
```